# useEffect Doesnt render the page Automatically in React JS

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I am trying to fetch the data from firebase using **useEffect** in React JS, But my problem is its not updating / rendering the page automatically when Any changes in database occurs.

**I Tried**

```
const [users,setUsers]=useState([]);

const usersCollectionRef=collection(db,"customers");

useEffect(()=>{
        const getUsers=async ()=>{
            const data=await getDocs(usersCollectionRef);
            setUsers(data.docs.map((doc)=>({...doc.data(),id:doc.id})))
        };
        getUsers();
        console.log(users)
    },[])
```

**and here returning the data**

```
return (
    <div className="App">
        {users.map((user)=>{
            return <h1 key={user.id}>{user.id}</h1>
        })}
    </div>
  )
```

**Please help me with this**

Comment: what do you mean by *Automatically* ?

Comment: Automatically means, Any changes in database should reflect here..

Comment: What about using **SWR**? React hooks for Data Fetching. I believe [this](https://swr.vercel.app/) answers your question.

Comment: You'll need to use `socket.io` to tell the frontend the database changed.

Comment: no, I want t use useState and useEffeect only.

Comment: If your database changes, then there is no way for the frontend in to know with just `useState` and `useEffect`.

Comment: How would the client knows that there is change happened in the DB that required him to send the fetch request (revalidate) with a component life cycle hooks?

Comment: Okay , So whats the solution for it. @Basbas

Comment: Okay, So I should go with the SWR ? @Amr

Comment: I would again, use `socket-io` and make a socket server in my backend. When the DB changes, i'll send a signal to the frontend. On the frontend, i'll listen for said signal then re-render the page. You may want to read up on sockets.

Comment: @stackOverflow, there should must a rule that, before MARKING QUESTION USELESS , user should must give reason. If we don't know the answer its very easy to mark useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use onSnapshot. It will update on every changes in collection.
So,
Answer

```
useEffect(() => {
        onSnapshot(usersCollectionRef, (snapshot) =>
            setUsers(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })))
        )
    }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

In the above code useEffect will execute only once because of empty dependency array.
You can remove dependency array to execute repeatedly or you can pass variables to execute whenever the data in the variable changes as below:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    Code
 })
```

Or

```
useEffect(()=>{
    Code
},[Variables])
```

Comment: useEffect(()=>{ Code }), It executes in loop

Answer (score 0):

Your `useEffect` will run only `once` because your `dependency list` its empty.

If you want to triger this useEffect you will add some condition to the dependency list.

More on that : `https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html`